# MUI component - styles from the theme context (Styled Components) don't apply in production when app's theme mode changes

Tags: next.js, material-ui, styled-components

In a Material-UI (MUI) component, styles from the theme context, implemented using Styled Components, are not applied in the production build when the application's theme mode changes.

Theme modes: light & dark.
Everything works correctly on localhost in dev mode.

The `theme` is provided correctly (works across the entire app). The `theme` object property names are also correct.

The problem occurs in `StyledAccordion` component.

**Component (I cut some unnecessary jsx)**

```
import {
  StyledSection,
  StyledArticle,
  StyledTextWrapper,
  StyledRozniceWrapper,
  StyledCard,
  StyledTitleWrapper,
  StyledAccordionWrapper,
  StyledAccordion,
  StyledAccordionDetails,
  StyledHeading,
  StyledButtonWrapper,
} from './rozniceSection.css';

import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';

import { StyledDiv } from '../_shared/styles/globalStyles';

import CustomLink from '../_shared/ui/customLink';

import Image from 'next/image';

const RozniceSection = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [isClientSide, setIsClientSide] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const { current: currentTheme } = useSelector((state: GlobalState) => state.theme);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClientSide(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <StyledSection>
      <StyledArticle>
        <StyledRozniceWrapper>
          <StyledDiv style={{ border: '3px solid #FCCF5B' }}>
            <StyledCard>
              <StyledAccordionWrapper>
                <StyledAccordion>
                  <AccordionSummary
                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                    aria-controls="panel2a-content"
                    id="panel2a-header"
                  >
                    <StyledHeading>
                      <span>
                        <Image height={2} width={155} alt="line" src="/decoration/line-thin.svg" />
                        Usługi dla mikro i małych
                      </span>{' '}
                      przedsiębiorców
                    </StyledHeading>
                  </AccordionSummary>
                  <StyledAccordionDetails>
                    <p>
                     Description …
                    </p>
                  </StyledAccordionDetails>
                </StyledAccordion>
              </StyledAccordionWrapper>
            </StyledCard>
          </StyledDiv>
        </StyledRozniceWrapper>

        <StyledButtonWrapper>
          <CustomLink href="/o-inicjatywie">Czytaj Więcej</CustomLink>
        </StyledButtonWrapper>
      </StyledArticle>
    </StyledSection>
  );
};

export default RozniceSection;
```

**Styled Components**

```
'use client';

import styled from 'styled-components';

import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';

export const StyledAccordion = styled(Accordion)`
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.cardBackground};
  border: ${({ theme }) => '1px solid' + theme.cardBorder};
  box-shadow: none;
`;
```

Any idea what causes the issue?

Answer (score 1):

After couple of hours of searching and going through the docs of MUI, I found the answer. For those, who may struggle with the same issue, I'm posting the answer below.

https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order

*Note: Most CSS-in-JS solutions inject their styles at the bottom of the HTML , which gives Material UI precedence over your custom styles. To remove the need for !important, you need to change the CSS injection order. Here's a demo of how it can be done in Material UI.*

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

export default function GlobalCssPriority() {
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      {/* Your component tree. Now you can override Material UI's styles. */}
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

However I still don't understand why it works in dev mode while in production it's not.